# How can I make this function run more than once?

Tags: c++

Let me first note that I am an absolute BEGINNER to C++. So please, go easy on me.

I've been writing the code below as part of an assignment for my Programming Methodology course this summer. It's meant to be a Bank program that takes user input to calculate the number of months (n), the interest rate (i) and the monthly payment for the user's loan. Then, the program is supposed to take a payment amount from the user and calculate a new balance. From here, it is supposed to print an amortization report that delineates the Beginning Balance, the Interest Paid, the Principle Paid, and the ending balance. All of this works well, but the next part I am having trouble with. The program is supposed to be able to take multiple payments and add additional lines to the amortization report, and I cannot figure out how to run the Make Payment function a second time to get those additional payments. Help, please!!

Also, I know that the parameters set for the member functions are almost needless, as they are replaced by user input, but they're required by the instructor in the assignment instructions.

Thanks again for any advice you can give!

```
#ifndef LOAN_DATA_H
#define LOAN_DATA_H

class Loan_Data
{
private:
    double  Bal;
    double  n;
    double  i;
    double  A;
        double p;

public:
            Loan_Data(double p, double n, double i);
    void    MakePayment(double pay);
    void    PrintAmortizationSchedule();
};

#endif  /* LOAN_DATA_H */




#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "Loan_Data.h"

using namespace std;


Loan_Data::Loan_Data(double p, double n, double i)
{
    cout << "Enter the loan amount: $";
    cin >> this->p;
    cout << "Enter the loan length: ";
    cin >> this->n;
    cout << "Enter your credit score: ";
    cin >> this->i;

    this->i = this->i / 100;
    this->i = this->i / 12;
    this->n = this->n * 12;
    Bal = this->p;
    A = (this->p * ((this->i * pow(1 + this->i, n)) / (pow(1 + this->i, n) - 1)));

    cout << "A is: " << A << endl;
    cout << "Bal is: " << Bal << endl;
    cout << "i is: " << this->i << endl;
}
void Loan_Data::MakePayment(double pay)
{
    cout << "i is: " << i << endl;
    cout << "Bal is: " << Bal << endl;
    cout << "Enter payment first payment amount: $";
    cin >> pay;

    cout << "Bal is: " << Bal << endl;

    Bal = ((i + 1) * Bal) - pay;
      A = pay;  
}

void Loan_Data::PrintAmortizationSchedule()
{
    double iP = (i * Bal);
    double pP = (A - (i*Bal));
    double endingBalance = ((1 + i)*Bal - A);
    double payment2 = (i + 1)*Bal;

    cout << "Beginning Bal." << "\t""\t" << cout << "Interest paid" << "\t""\t" << cout << "Principle paid" << "\t""\t" << cout << "Ending Bal." << "\t""\t" << endl;

     if ((i + 1)*Bal > A)
     {
         cout << p << "\t""\t""\t""\t" << iP << "\t""\t""\t""\t" << pP << "\t\t""\t""\t" << endingBalance << endl;
         endingBalance = Bal;
     }
     else if (Bal < A)
     {
         cout << Bal << "\t""\t""\t""\t" << iP << "\t""\t""\t""\t" << (payment2 - (i*Bal)) << "\t\t""\t""\t" << ((1 + i)*Bal - payment2) << endl;
         Bal = ((1 + i)*Bal - payment2);
     }
     else if (Bal == 0)
     {
         cout << "0" << "\t""\t""\t""\t""\t" << "0" << "\t""\t""\t""\t""\t" << "0" << "\t\t""\t""\t""\t" << "0" << endl;
     }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double Bal;
    double p;
    double n;
    double i;
    double pay;
    double A; 


    Loan_Data loan1(p, n, i);

    loan1.MakePayment(pay);

    loan1.PrintAmortizationSchedule();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can use a [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) or [while loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your main using **[do while](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html)** loops --

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char ch='n';
do {
 double Bal;
 double p;
 double n;
 double i;
 double pay;
 double A;
 Loan_Data loan1(p, n, i);
 loan1.MakePayment(pay);
 loan1.PrintAmortizationSchedule();
 printf("Do you want to continue ");
 ch=getchar();
 }while(ch=='y');
return 0;

}
```

Do while loop repeats your code that is enclosed while the condition is true i.e, if user enters y at end of 1st time the program will continue else it would exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a piece of code run more than once depending on a "condition", then use [c++ while loop](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/18869/) or a [c++ for loop.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm)

```
while(condition){
 execute function;
}
for(variable; condition; variable modification){
 execute function;
}
```